# Spatial index grid size is invalid

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-desktop

I am trying to move a point feature programmatically, but on stop operation, I am getting this error:

```
spatial index grid size is invalid.
```

Assuming that new features are being added in an edit session, how would one go about avoiding this error when loading large amounts of features programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You may have to recreate or recalculate the spatial index of your feature class, see link below.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=2047&pid=2045&topicname=Setting_spatial_indexes

Comment: I am writing the code in Event trapper and calling a function from different class to move the feature. The same function I am calling for a different requirement where it is working properly. But from event trapper it is giving the above error.

Comment: @Sheethal Are you using thread where you get this error message?